# Codeigniter: Categories and Subcategroies

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach, codeigniter-datamapper

I am trying to make a restaurant menu and I have to have **Categories** and **Subcategories**, so I created the following tables:

```
Table: Categories
       ID
       NAME

Table: Subcategories
       ID
       NAME
       PRICE
       DESCRIPTION
       CATEGORIES_ID
```

I am using Codeigniter and DataMapper PHP by wanwizard. So currently I have some version of 2 foreach loops but the problem is that when I add a new SUBCATEGORY and only the last one appear, **so it is NOT listing all the subcategories of the category** Any ideas where I am wrong ?

```
public function index()
{

$categories = new Category_model();
$subcategories = new Subcategory_model();
$categories->get();
$subcategories->get();

$recent_categories = array();
foreach ($categories as $category)
{
  foreach($subcategories as $subcategory)
  {
    if($subcategory->categories_id == $category->id)
    {
      $single_category = array
      (
        'category_name' => $category->name,
        'subcategory_name' => $subcategory->name,
        'subcategory_description' => $subcategory->description,
        'subcategory_price' => $subcategory->price,
      );
    }
  }
  array_push($recent_categories, $single_category);
}

$data = array
(
  'categories' => $recent_categories,
);

$this->parser->parse('templates/content_menu', $data);
}
```

THIS IS THE VIEW:

```
{categories}
  <div class="grid-12 ourmenu">
    <!-- MENU TITLE -->
    <h2>{category_name}</h2>
    <hr/>
      <!-- MENU ITEM -->
      <h4>
        <a class="clb-photo" href="<?php echo site_url('design/images/photos/food.jpg'); ?>">
          {subcategory_name}
        </a>
        <span>{subcategory_price}</span>
      </h4>
      <p>{subcategory_description}</p>
  </div>
  {/categories}
```

Comment: You lost me at... _So currently I have some version of 2 foreach loops but the problem is that when I add a new SUBCATEGORY and only the last one appear_ what is "some version of 2 foreach loops?" And "only the last one appear" -where does the last one appear? Did you check database to see if it is there? You need to provide better clarity to your problem statement

Comment: Look at the code I have given. When I add a new SUBCATEGORY and I go at the view and view the results, I see only the last entry and the previous one is gone. So it looks like this:
--CATEGORY--
  -- SUBCATEGORY--
--CATEGORY--
  -- SUBCATEGORY-- and I have to have more than one SUBCATEGORY but it is displaying only one

Comment: when you print $data in this page you only get last record?

Comment: I only get the last record for the SUBCATEGORY otherwise the CATEGORIES are there like they should be. Check the FOREACH LOOPS I think there I am wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in your structure of the loops. You need to do the `array_push` INSIDE the `foreach($subcategories as $subcategory)` loop. Your `single_category` array is overwritten with each iteration of the loop, but it is never added to the `recent_categories` array until after is has been overwritten. Change your code to:

```
foreach ($categories as $category)
{
  foreach($subcategories as $subcategory)
  {
    if($subcategory->categories_id == $category->id)
    {
      $single_category = array
      (
        'category_name' => $category->name,
        'subcategory_name' => $subcategory->name,
        'subcategory_description' => $subcategory->description,
        'subcategory_price' => $subcategory->price,
      );
      array_push($recent_categories, $single_category); // ****** MOVED THIS LINE 
    }
  }
}
```